# update using useState is not re-rendering the page in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have below code, where I need to render the input field on double click on td tag

```
const [getTableData, setTableData] = useState(tableData);

//td tag in the HTML table
    {getTableData.map((data, index) => (
                        <tr key={index}>
                            <td>{index + 1}</td>
                            <td onDoubleClick={handleDateDoubleClick} data-key={data.uniqueKey}>
                                {renderDate(data)}
                            </td>
    </tr>
    ))}

// handles double click 
function handleDateDoubleClick(event) {
        let currentRecord = getTableData.find(data => {
            if (+(data.uniqueKey) === +(event.target.dataset.key)) {
                data.readOnlyDate = data.readOnlyDate ? false : true;
                return data;
            }
        })

        setTableData([...getTableData]); // using spread operator but still no luck.
        renderDate(currentRecord); // explicitly calling renderDate method still nothing.
        console.log(JSON.stringify(currentRecord));
    }
//conditionally render the input field.
    const renderDate = (data) => {
        if (data.readOnlyDate) {
            return data.Date
        } else {
            return (
                <FormControl
                    value={data.Date}
                    data-key={data.uniqueKey}
                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                />
            );
        }
    }
```

in console log I can see array is updated but still not re rendering the page with input field instead of static text, please confirm if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mutating the existing state, so React isn't re-checking the object's contents:

```
data.readOnlyDate = data.readOnlyDate ? false : true;
```

Never mutate state in React. Instead, *clone* the object.

```
const index = getTableData.findIndex(data => +(data.uniqueKey) === +(event.target.dataset.key));
const currentRecord = getTableData[index];
const newRecord = { ...currentRecord, readOnlyDate: !currentRecord.readOnlyDate };
setTableData([
  ...getTableData.slice(0, index),
  newRecord,
  ...getTableData.slice(index + 1),
]);
renderDate(newRecord);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help, would you please do me another favor and help me to understand the reason for .slice method here with spread operator?

Comment: You need to call `setTableData` with a new array structure, so you `.slice` the array before and after the index of the new object to insert, and put the new object in between those slices. Since the new object has to be *new* (and not a mutation of the old state object), you have to copy the old object, which can be done with object spread syntax.